# Pig: Accessing inner tuples' fields for filtering

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have [a custom Pig loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/udf.html#load-store-functions) like this:

```
A = LOAD 'myfile' USING myudf_loader()
```

`A` contains:

```
((key1, val1), (key2, val2), (key3, val3), ...)
```

That is `A` has an outer tuple that contains key-value pairs stored in inner tuples.

I am not using maps because maps require that [key values within a relation must be unique](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Data+Types+and+More). The keys I have do not necessarily have to be unique.

The keys are `chararrays`, while the values can be `chararrays`, `ints`, and `floats`.

I would like to access `A`'s inner tuples, as well as the (key, value) pairs within those tuples.

For example, I want to `FILTER` the keys of `A` such that the only fields remaining are `key = "city"` and `value = "New York City"`.

Example input:

```
DUMP A;
(("city", "New York City"), ("city", "Boston"),
 ("city", "Washington, D.C."), ("non-city-key", "non-city-value"),
 ("city", "New York City"), ("non-city-key", "non-city-value"))
```

Example output of the filtering, which is stored into `B`:

```
DUMP B;
("city", "New York City")
("city", "New York City")
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont have your full pig latin script.

But you can achieve using the below idea

```
grouped_records = GROUP records By Key;

filtered_records = FILTER grouped_records By group='CITY'

Dump filtered_records
```

Cheers
Nag

Comment: Thank you, but this answer doesn't show how to access the inner tuples. Like key1 in ((key1, val1), (key2, val2), ..., (keyn, valn)).